# Quemar la etiqueta [Backend]

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, solicitud-de-quemado

Las estadisticas de uso dicen que es una etiqueta con 6 preguntas.

- 4 comparten uso con [frontend](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frontend)
- 1 viene con [angularjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs)
- 1 viene con [joomla3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/joomla3)

La etiqueta es una meta etiqueta. Una pregunta que hable sobre back end solamente, seria valida en un contexto de arquitectura, y probablemente sea sujeta a opiniones.

Comment: 6 apariciones parece ser un número lo suficientemente pequeño como para que se haga manualmente, ¿no?

Comment: sip, pero va a volver a aparecer.. te lo firmo.. no me cuesta nada borrarlas.. mas que eso habria que banearla..

Comment: No sé qué tan ágil es el proceso de poner una etiqueta en la lista negra, pues depende de un CM. El marcaje de [tag:google] se solicitó hace casi dos meses y [no veo que se haya realizado](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2685/83).

Comment: @fedorqui es lento, y por eso estoy poniendo un post por dia.. tengo para dos dias mas todavia :p.. pero Lois esta al tanto, y ya le escribimos a Juan